# Call function inside dynamically created button

Tags: javascript

Hy,

I am trying to execute a function, more precisely clear a canvas for redrawing,within a dynamically created button. addButton function is called inside the click event of an existing button on the interface. The code it's this:

```
function addButton()
{
var canvas=document.getElementById('CrosswordSpace');
this.context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var parent = document.getElementsByName('gen')[0].parentNode;
var element=document.createElement("input");
element.type='button';
element.name='buttonAnswer';
element.value='Show answer';
element.onclick=function()
{
    this.context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
}
 parent.appendChild(element);
this.onclick=null;
 }
```

The error says 'cannot call method clearRect of undefined.
If you're asking why do I have this.onclick=null, it is because before using this statement the dynamically created button would duplicate itself each time I would press the main button, and I don't want that.
Anyway, if I call inside onclick of dynamically created button,any other function that works
elsewhere(tested) seems not to be working anymore.
In conclusion, the question is,how to call a function inside onclick event of dynamically created button?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to preserve the `this` value from the original method to be used in the callback because the callback can change the meaning of `this`

```
var self = this;
element.onclick=function()
{
    self.context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
}
```